(Necessary and sufficient) Conditions for the Ricci tensor of an affine connection to be symmetric.
Let $\nabla$ be an affine connection on a smooth manifold $M$. It is widely known, that if $\nabla$ is torsion-free, then its Ricci tensor is symmetric iff there exists a volume form $\omega$ on $M$ such that $\nabla \omega=0$ - this is called a parallel volume form and $\nabla$ is said to be an equiaffine connection.
If we now weaken the assumption of $\nabla$ being torsion-free, is there a characterization/sufficient and/or necessary conditions for its Ricci tensor to be symmetric?
It is clear to me that this is the case for the Levi-Civita connection, but I mean for other affine connections, which are not the Levi-Civita.
